# Change one column's name in R

Tags: r

I need to change a specific column name in R. I used the following command but it did not change anything.

```
colnames(mydata[3])<-"newname"
```

"3" is the column number

Comment: Try `colnames(mydata)[3] <- "newname"`

Comment: sometimes its usefull to change column name by name not by its place like 
    colnames(mydata)[colnames(mydata)=="oldname"] <- "newname"

Comment: @Pigeon is this will change columns that have names like "oldname1" with the "newname1"?

Comment: Yes it will change oldname1 to newname1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colnames(mydata)[3] <- "newname"`. `colnames` is a vector itself, so just move your `[3]` outside it.